# How do I get the SUM of MAX/exceed value from a row/range in excel?

Tags: excel

Below is the sample data.

How do I get all values that exceeded the amount 200? In this case, I have 2 instances of over 200. My result should be 50+50 = 100

This should do it right?
`=SUM(MAX(A1-200,0),MAX(A2-200,0))` so on..

But is there like a better way of using a range instead of adding the result of each cell, say..

`foreach cell in this range, if cell > 200, excessAmount++`?

[image]

Comment: Try sumifs(), on phone otherwise I would test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=SUMIF(A1:F2,">200")-200*COUNTIF(A1:F2,">200")`

This sums values over 200, then subtracts 200 from each of those to arrive at the excess.

You can move the constant `200` to its own cell and use a named range if you like:

`=SUMIF(MyRange,">" & $A$5)-$A$5*COUNTIF(MyRange,">" &$A$5)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using this simple formula:

```
=SUM(IF(B3:I3<=200,0,B3:I3-200))
```

It means:

- If a value is smaller than 200, use 0.
- else (value being larger than 200), use "200 - value".

=> Take the sum.

Oh, you can use an entire range as an input: I have done this for all cells in the range `B3:I3`.

In your question, you mention:

```
=SUM(MAX(A1-200,0),MAX(A2-200,0))
```

This can be written as:

```
=SUM(MAX(A1:A2-200,0))
```

Comment: This looks more understandable, but I am having an `#VALUE` error on calculating the if condition. I don't think excel loops each cell when you input a range like that. Anyway, thanks for the input.

Comment: @AdorableVB: if you have `#VALUE` errors at `=IF()`, it might mean that your Excel is not in English, and you might replace it by `=SI()` (I see you're from the Philippines, that's Spanish, isn't it?).

Comment: IMO, this is a better answer (I didn't see it before I posted mine).

Answer (score 1):

Formula for Microsoft 365 users:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B3:H3-200,B3:H3>200))
```

FILTER function returns an array of values subtracted by 200 when the condition >200 is satisfied. This array is then summed by the SUM function.

Sadly, spill arrays are not available to Excel 2019 users and below. So FILTER function cannot be used.

For others: VBA Code

```
sum = 0
For Each cell In Range('Your Range Here').Cells
    If cell.Value > 200 Then sum = sum + cell.Value - 200
Next cell
```